# How to avoid the overuse of dynamic casting when it comes to polymorphic types / am I using them correctly for my AST?

Tags: c++, casting, compiler-construction, polymorphism, abstract-syntax-tree

I have written a compiler that works in its current form. However I feel like I am overusing dynamic casting when differentiating different sub classes for the nodes while visiting nodes on the AST. Here is an example:

I have a recursive method called `visit` that dynamically casts a node parameter for each node sub class. It will check if the cast was successful and then take appropriate action as such:

```
VariableValue visit(Node *node) {
    Num* num = dynamic_cast<Num*>(node);
    if (num != NULL) {
        return visit_Num(num);
    }
    delete num;
    BinOp* binop = dynamic_cast<BinOp*>(node);
    if (binop != NULL) {
        return visit_BinOp(binop);
    }
    delete binop;
    UnOp* unop = dynamic_cast<UnOp*>(node);
    if (unop != NULL) {
        return visit_UnaryOp(unop);
    }
    delete unop;
    ...
```

The issue is I have a lot of different node sub classes, so these blocks of if statements go on for a while. I feel this approach is not very efficient on CPU and memory as a cast will be created for each node sub class and will have to be checked against each one. I have attempted to improve this by using `delete` when a cast fails.

Is there a better way to achieve my desired results within a polymorphic environment?

For some context here are the node classes including the parent:

```
class Node {
    public:
        virtual std::string toString() = 0;
        virtual int getNodeAttribute() { return 0; }
        Token token;
        Node(){}
};

class BinOp : public Node{
    public:
        Node *left, *right; 
        Token op;
        BinOp(Node *cleft, Token cop, Node *cright) {
            left = cleft;
            Node::token = cop;
            op = cop;
            right = cright;
        }
        std::string toString() {
            return "BinOp Node";
        }
};

class Num : public Node{
    public:
        TokenValue value;
        Num(Token ctoken) {
            Node::token = ctoken;
            value = ctoken.value;
        }
        std::string toString() {
            return "Num Node";
        }
};

class UnOp : public Node {
    public:
        Node *expr;
        UnOp(Token ctoken, Node *cexpr) {
            Node::token = ctoken;
            expr = cexpr;
        }
        std::string toString() {
            return "UnOp Node";
        }
};

...
```

And here is how a node is generated within the parser (`Num` node for example)

```
Node* Parser::factor() {
    ...
    else if (token.type == TOKENTYPE::INTEGER) {
        eat(TOKENTYPE::INTEGER);
        Num* numNode = new Num(token);
        return numNode;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: If all your `Node`s contain an `enum` which identifies the type, then why not use it with a `static_cast` instead of a `dynamic_cast`? Also, unrelated, you should use `nullptr` not `NULL`.

Comment: "I have attempted to improve this by using delete when a cast fails." Fortunately for you, that will do nothing since the target of the `delete`s are guaranteed to be null pointers. `dynamic_cast` does not create a new object; it simply gives you a reference; if you managed to delete that reference, it would impact the original object. (Your base type doesn't seem to have a virtual destructor, by the way. I suppose that's because you didn't include it in your excerpt.)

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of those `delete`s. Their arguments are all `nullptr`. And, if they weren't, you'd be deleting something that doesn't belong to that function.

Comment: There is no impact on "memory" here. CPU, yes...

Comment: Also, check out `std::variant`. It's closer to the functionality you want.

Comment: @rici It pretty much _is_ this functionality (modulo Chris's suggestion)

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0: Maybe that comment could have been more definite :-)

Comment: The perhaps best approach could be to look how LLVM (clang) is doing that kind of stuff: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/include/clang/AST/RecursiveASTVisitor.h

Comment: Why isn't `visit` a virtual member of `Node`?  Then each derived type would have its own implementation of it and call the proper function.

Comment: Hi thanks for the feed back guys. @ChrisMM I have gone with your approach: 
 if (node->nodeType == NODETYPE::NUM) {
 Num* cnode = static_cast<Num*>(node);
 return visit_Num(cnode);
}